# Who owned Tyraxes?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons

I'm currently reading [The World of Ice and Fire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Ice_%26_Fire), essentially a "behind the scenes" for ASOIAF, and while reading the section on the Dance of Dragons, I noticed something that confused me.

On page 81, when detailing the dragons involved in the Dance, the book says

> Vermax (Prince Jacaerys): Young but strong, killed **with his rider** at the Battle of the Gullet
>
> [...]
>
> Tyraxes (Prince Jacaerys): Young but strong, killed at the Storming of the Dragonpit

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Clearly, these two dragons contradict each other in terms of who owns them as Jacaerys was killed with Vermax. This means that Tyraxes doesn't have an owner, according to the book.

I am assuming that this is an error, so who actually owned and rode Tyraxes?

Comment: Please consider marking the answer which you found the best with a green check mark (found under the scores)

Answer (score 10):

In the short story "The Princess and the Queen", or, The Blacks and the Greens, Tyraxes is described as being ridden by Joffrey Velaryon.

> Even young **Joffrey chimed in, offering to mount his own dragon Tyraxes** and join his brothers.
>
> Jace ordered Prince Joffrey to fly to Gulltown with Tyraxes.
>
> Another fleet set out from Gulltown with Prince Joffrey, the last of the queen’s three sons by Laenor Velaryon, together with his dragon Tyraxes.
>
> This prospect excited Prince Joffrey. “Let them come,” the boy announced, “I will meet them on Tyraxes.

As for Tyraxes' death, it reconfirms that Tyraxes was killed in the storming of the Dragonpit.

> Prince Joffrey’s Tyraxes retreated back into his lair, we are told, roasting so many would-be dragonslayers
> [...]
> Half a dozen men (and one woman) would later claim to have dealt the dragon the mortal blow.

It would seem this is in fact a mistake on behalf of The World of Ice and Fire, and Tyraxes was actually ridden by Joffrey Velaryon.

Comment: +1 for quoting TPATQ. Only thing to note, this is not a universal mistake but rather a printing mistake in OP's specific copy or edition.

Comment: I thought mine wasn't correct, but I thought maybe mine was the odd one out :P

Answer (score 5):

Your book is wrong. For my own copy and the one used by [asearchoficeandfire.com quotes tool](https://asearchoficeandfire.com/?q=Young%20but%20strong%2C%20killed%20at%20the%20Storming%20of%20the%20Dragonpit&scope%5B%5D=twoiaf), It says:

> VERMAX (Prince Jacaerys): Young but strong, killed with his rider at
>   the Battle of the Gullet.
>   ARRAX (Prince Lucerys): Young but strong, killed with his rider by
>   Vhagar above Shipbreaker Bay.
>
> **TYRAXES (Prince Joffrey)**: Young but strong, killed at the Storming of
>   the Dragonpit.

So evidently it's a mistake in your particular edition/copy. Edolthiad has already provided the evidence that Tyraxes was bound to Prince Joffrey Velaryon, not his elder brother.

I'll just add the info he hasn't added. The Dragon Tyraxes was actually hatched from the egg given to Prince Joffrey by his Grandfather, the King.

> By royal decree, **each of the Velaryon boys was presented with a
>   dragon’s egg whilst in the cradle**. Those who doubted the paternity
>   of Rhaenyra’s sons whispered that the eggs would never hatch, but the
>   birth in turn of three young dragons gave the lie to their words.
>   **The hatchlings were named Vermax, Arrax, and Tyraxes**. 
> <sub>***The Rogue Prince***</sub>

So Joffrey was Tyraxes' first and last rider. The dragon accompanied the Prince to Vale and to King's Landing. There it was killed in Storming of the dragonpit while the Prince tumbled to his death while trying to master her Mother's dragon Syrax who threw him down.